# Python code not executing when nesting functions

Tags: python

when I execute this code, no question prompted as a result of the input command.

putting the code in a file then typing in Visual Studio Code
python `filename.py`
no output from the code, just getting a new line on the console

```
def main():
    x = int(input("what is x? "))
    if is_even(x):
        print ("even")
    else:
        print ("odd")


def is_even(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

    
main()
```

Comment: the code works. `what is x? 12
even`

Comment: Did you **save** the code file in VS Code after typing it in?

Comment: thanks for the replies
Indeed the file was saved. However, when I simply closed VS Code and opened it again, the code executed correctly. I have seen this behaviour now few times with other codes. Happy to live with this feature